# Prove that $x<y$ if $2^a-y=x$ where $2^a$ is the smallest power of 2 greater or equal to $y$. All variables are positive integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Prove that $x<y$ if $2^a-y=x$ where $2^a$ is the smallest power of 2 greater or equal to $y$. All variables are positive integers. How should I prove this? I'm new to proofs, and I saw this in a forum.

Comment: Hint:  if $x≥y$ then show that $2^a=y+x≥2y$.  Deduce that $2^{a-1}≥y$ .

Comment: Hint: Suppose $2^{a-1} < y \leq 2^{a}$, where $a$ is an appropriately chosen integer. What can u say about $x = 2^{a}-y$?

Comment: By " positive integers" do you mean integers greater or equal to 0, or integers strictly greater than 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets consider the maximum gap between $2$ consecutive powers of $2$

$2^{n+1}-2^n$

$2^n(2-1)=2^n$

Let $2^n\lt y \leq 2^{n+1}$
and maximum gap can be $2^n-1$,

and $y\gt 2^n$ so $y\gt 2^{n-1}$
and $y\gt x$.